# Discrepancy in reputation points

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation points in stackoverflow.com is 178. However when i open my profile at 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/166012?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top

and check reputation it shows somewhere around 240. Any idea what is wrong.

Comment: interesting reputation graph indeed...

Comment: why do you say so. Once i offered a bounty on my question and hance lost some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Currently shows 202 for you. Look closely at that list if you want to audit it.

Comment: I can see an entry 
12  2698270 (-100) but why would i loose 100 points in one shot.

Comment: Ahh, you got 6 spams flag answering [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698257/how-software-configuration-management-help-in-improving-project-management) questions with content - `Use FogBugz :) and it will take care of everything and Kiln` Imm

Comment: @viswanathan - you lose 100 rep if 6 (I think) people flag one of your posts as spam/offensive (See S.Mark's comment).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to request for recalculation, by flagging one of your post to moderators.

Here is my calculation

```
Questions: 225 
Answers: 90 
Lost: -58 (-50 from bounty, -8 from downvotes you got)
Answers you accepted: 48 
Downvoted by you: -5 
Initial: 1
```

You should have, around `301`, but currently `193`, may be one of your answer/question got flagged as spam or offensive? If thats is the case, you wouldn't get points back with recalc.

Have you experienced one of your post got downvoted a lot recently?

**Edit**: Let me make it up my calculations once I know the answer.

My above calculations: `301`
You lose: `-100` from that post
that results in `201`, but actual one is 202 according to Jeff, so probably one of the post you downvoted is got deleted :-)

Comment: Sure let me check that.

Comment: No one of my questions got closed as it was duplicate but i dont think it got downvoted so many times. How do i check if anything was flagged offensive.

Comment: @viswanatha, I added some details on my calculations on your profile. but lets see, if you don't get points back with recalc, probably one of your posts got 6 flags of spam or offensive. and we can't check for now, I am not sure moderator could find or not. but anyway, please request recalc to mods to make one thing clear.

Comment: Maybe but i dont think i have posted something that can be flagged spam or offensive. Anyway let me cross check

Comment: Its not about anything recent. ALl of a sudden 2 weeks back my reputation showed 4 instead of some 100. However the graph was showing everything correctly.

Comment: yes i get it but still the graph must also match with my actual reputation right?

Comment: @viswanatha, may be graph don't display deleted post. but I am not so sure about that, because some users's -100 can see in rep-graph

Comment: @viswanatha, you could raise new question, about why you can't see that -100 in your rep-graph and but others can see, for example - [Evan Carrol](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135854?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top)